# Old laptop cannot boot from ubuntu 15.10 dvd

Tags: boot, 15.10, laptop, hp, dvd

I have ab old nc8000 laptop with 14.04 installed on it. I want to upgrade to 15.10 but the laptop cannot boot from the install dvd. Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks :)

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using Server Edition. Also, I don't ever want this laptop to go online. So want to do the upgrade with a dvd if possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can only upgrade from LTS to LTS, or to the next 6-monthly release. While you may attempt to do something else, it is NOT supported.

---

To upgrade from **14.04 LTS**, then either wait for **16.04 LTS** (April 2016) or try a new install of **15.10** on a separate partition/drive (or spare platform).

*Do not attempt to upgrade from **14.04 LTS** directly to **15.10**.*

Comment: Is it a simple matter to format the drive and go to 15.10? I have encrypted the drive and the home folder. Thanks :)

Comment: While you can just backup (all data and settings), and then do a clean install of **15.10**, I would strongly recommend testing for device compatibility first. *The drive being encrypted is just the data, and this will simply be overwritten during install (and any data not saved elsewhere will be lost).*.

Comment: Thanks i guess the best bet is to wait for 16.04. I didn't know you have to go from LTS to LTS only. If my old machine doesn't like 14 LTS too uch i doubt it will like 15.10. Does that sound accurate?

Comment: Basically: Any issues with upgrading from **14.04 LTS** to latest are being address (as we speak) by Ubuntu developers; and will incorporated into **16.04 LTS**. Any upgrade issues will also be supported/addressed ..

Comment: @kipper, if you have sensitve data on your laptop, which is quite old, and want it to stay offline -as you say in another question - may I suggest Lubuntu, or some other lightweight distribution? Just Google "Linux for old laptops" to get more suggestions. May I also suggest you combine your two questions into this one, for clarity's sake? I think the mods are always trying to prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I had one of these too. I would go with lubuntu on these machines. Problem is, that the Pentium M CPU in the nc8000 doesn't have the PAE feature, required with newer versions of Ubuntu.

I would wait for 16.04 and do a system upgrade. This is the best (only) way to go. A new installation will be more complicated because of the (mentioned) missing PAE feature in your CPU.

Comment: Thanks minimec. But wouldn't 16.04 still be problematic to use because of the lack of PAE support or could I get away with it?

Comment: It should work. It's only a question of the kernel. The xUbuntu.iso's only come with a PAE kernels. Only the Lubuntu.iso has a nonPAE Kernel. 

So you can upgrade to a new version,  if you have a system with a nonPAE kernel installed, but you can only do a fresh installation with Lubuntu, if you have a nonPAE CPU. That's how I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a USB flash drive laying around, you could always use it to install Ubuntu that way. Please note that this will start a fresh installation, which may overwrite your files, depending on how your partitions are set up.

[Download the ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) for your architecture (32-bit or 64-bit). Fire up the terminal on your Ubuntu computer, insert your flash drive, and type in `sudo parted` and enter your root password. Then type `print devices`. This will output all storage devices connected to your system. Look for a device which matches your flash drive's capacity. It will have a name like this `/dev/sdx`, where x will be a letter from a-z. Open up another terminal, and navigate to your Downloads-folder, using `cd Downloads`. Then type `sudo dd if=NameOfIsoFile.iso of=/dev/sdx`.

This will write the ISO image to the flash drive, and will DELETE ALL EXISTING DATA on it. There will not be a progress bar of any sort - just the flashing underscore, which will continue to flash until the operation is complete.

I hope this will come to help.

Comment: Thanks but this laptop is so old it doesn't have a 'boot from usb' option in the bios. :(